# commandLink rerender pageblockTable not refreshed after save

Tags: rerender, pageblocktable, commandlink, outputpanel

```
<apex:pageBlock id="SortByDirectionBlock" rendered="{!checkHFStatus}">
     <apex:commandLink action="{!saveSelectedMatches}" styleClass="navbar-link"  value="Save Students" reRender="StudentListBlock"  status="waitMsg">
     <apex:param value="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
     </apex:commandLink>
</apex:pageBlock>


 <apex:outputPanel id="StudentListBlock" >                             
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!engListWrap}" var="item" rendered="{!IF(engListWrap.Size > 0, true, false)}">
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</outputPanel>
```

I tried everything, but the pageblocktable is not refreshed after save!!!

I know we dont need to use ActionSupport for commandLink. this should work. Did I miss anything?

Comment: You sure that `engListWrap` condition is valid and list is not empty?

Comment: Your title says PageBlockTable isn't rendering and the body of the questions says PageBlock isn't rendering.

Comment: Yes, the rows in the pageblocktable are displaying. There is a checkbox in one of the columns.. Ideally, I tick one of them. CLick Save. Then the checkbox will be replaced by a text. THe problem is.. after I select 1 row, click Save, the pageblockTable remains same with a ticked checkbox,  (the code is working also). And if I refresh the page now, the checkbox is replaced with text. That implies - the pageblocktable is not rendering after I click save. i had to refresh the page everytime to see the checkbox convert to text.

Comment: I edited the subject.. the pageblocktable is not refreshed after save!

Comment: In order to answer properly, we'd need your controller code as well. There might be an issue in order of execution.

Comment: Did you try `rerender="{!$Component.greatgrandparent.grandparent.parent.StudentListBlock}"` where greatgrandparent, grandparent and parent refer to ids that are ancestors of StudentListBlock? (number of ancestors may vary based on your component hierarchy)

Comment: It is entirely possible that your wrapper in your controller is not being updated on save which is why the data in the table appears to not change until you reload the page which would regenerate the wrapper.. Controller code would be needed to help you if this is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. At the end of the save method, Im calling the method which fills my pageblocktable again.  This way, after the records are saved, im re fetching the data to display.  Because on re-render the records are not refreshed even though the pageblocktable is refreshed.

Comment: do you have the sample code on how you did that?

Comment: this is solving the issue.but still not able to find what is the rootcause of rerender not working in commandlink. =(

Answer (score 0):

Having the controller code would be helpful. I would be curious what your saveSelectedMatches does, how it parses out the wrapper and saves the data, and what the engListWrap list does to get populated and/or cleared.

I would assume that either, your saveSelectedMatches is not pulling back the checkbox selection correctly, or if it is, it is not saving it into your system correctly.
If that is not the case, I wonder if your engListWrap is getting cleared and re-queried when you call the getter method.